# blackberry image processing

Tags: blackberry

I am very new to Blackberry development.
I am working with an Blackberry project.
In this project i want to change image effects and control.!
Image effects are sepia,sketch,grayscale,negative ,flip etc
and controls are brightness,contrast,hue etc

I have tried for flip image effect. following is code that i hav tried..
I got the output but it is overlapped with original image.

[image effect-flip output]

anybody can solve this issue??

Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap) {

```
    int[] argb = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getARGB(argb, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getWidth(); j++) {
            int swap = argb[i * bitmap.getWidth() + j];
            argb[(bitmap.getHeight() - 1 - i) * bitmap.getWidth() + j] = swap;
        }
    }


    //bitmap.setARGB(data, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    Graphics gr=new Graphics(bitmap);
    gr.clear(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    bitmap.setARGB(argb, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());


    return bitmap;
}
```

anybody can solve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip on a new argb (called argb_flip) as in:

```
public Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap) {

        int[] argb = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

        int[] argb_flip = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

        bitmap.getARGB(argb, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getHeight(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getWidth(); j++) {
                int swap   = argb[i * bitmap.getWidth() + j];

                argb_flip[(bitmap.getHeight() - 1 - i) * bitmap.getWidth() + j] = swap;
            }
        }

        bitmap.setARGB(argb_flip, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: k.If i want to flop (mirror) the image what should i do?